# How to draw this figure (if possible in 3D)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-3dplot

I want to draw a figure whose rough and symbolic figure is attached. Here $K_m$ denote a complete graph on $m$ vertices. Each vertex of $K_m$ is attached with each vertex of $K_n$ as well $K_1$. For simplicity, one may take $m=5$ and $n=3$. I was trying it by taking an example from [Texample.net](http://www.texample.net) but failed.

**New edit:**

Now I have tried following for *m=8* and *n=3*. Can I further short the codes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning,graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \x in {1,...,8}{%
    \node[shape=circle,draw,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (d\x) at (0,{4*cos((\x-1)*45)},{4*sin((\x-1)*45)}) {};}
\node[shape=circle,draw,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (O) at (-5,0,0){};
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{%
  \node[shape=circle,draw,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (t\x) at (5,{4*cos((\x-1)*120)},{4*sin((\x-1)*120)}) {};}
\foreach \d in {1,...,8}{
\draw[color=blue] (O)--(d\d);}
\foreach \x in {1,...,8}{
\foreach \y in {\x,...,8}{
 \draw[color=red] (d\x)--(d\y);}}
\foreach \x in {1,...,8}{
\foreach \y in {1,2,3}{
\draw[color=green] (d\x)--(t\y);}}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\foreach \y in {\x,...,3}{
 \draw[color=black] (t\x)--(t\y);}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph $\Gamma_1$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image: figure]

Comment: Question titles consisting of "How to draw this..." without any indication to what "this" is in the title, is a bit bad practice for referencing and archival reasons. If this type of figure has a name, it should be added to the question title.

Comment: Since this is just a set of points and lines, it should be pretty straightforward. You could for example do the "connect any verted in Km with all vertices in Kn" part using two nested `\foreach` loops. However, without any indications of what you tried so far, this is just *"draw this for me, please"*, and not a question. So what have you tried and what are your problems. If possible, please give a complete, compilable LaTeX document, which illustrates your difficulties.

Comment: Thanks to @morbusg for the suggestion about title. I shall keep it in mind for next question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Fritz I am sorry for i did not tell "my try". Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: For your edit you need to write `\node[draw,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (d\x) at (0,{2*cos((\x-1)*45)},{2*sin((\x-1)*45)}) {};`

Comment: Do you need the internal connections, shown in red? Or simply the boundary of an octagon.

Comment: @Jesse Yes. I need.

Comment: Your `tizkpicture` environment did not take the advantage of the viewing angle as my answer showed (need to add `tdplot_main_coords`) and try this viewing angle `\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{60}` in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible solution where `tikz-3dplot` is used to draw a 3D diagram. The coordinates can be removed by marking them out. Different perspective angle can be adjusted via, for example, setting

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{120}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, tdplot_main_coords,axis/.style={->,dashed},thick]
\node[shape=circle,draw,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (O) at (0,-2,2){};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (3, 0, 0) node [right] {$X$};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 3, 0) node [above] {$Y$};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 0, 3) node [above] {$Z$};
\coordinate  (d1) at (1,0,3){};
\coordinate  (d2) at (-1,0,3){};
\coordinate  (d3) at (0,0,1){};
\coordinate  (d4) at (0,0,4){};
\draw [] (d1) -- (d4)--(d2)--(d3)--cycle;

\coordinate  (t1) at (1,2.,4){};
\coordinate  (t2) at (-1,2,4){};
\coordinate  (t3) at (0,2,2){};
\draw (t1)--(t2)--(t3)--cycle;
\foreach \d in {1,2,3,4}{
\draw[color=red] (O)--(d\d);
}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}{
\foreach \j in {1,2,3}{
\draw[color=red] (d\i)--(t\j);
}}
\node at (0,0,0.5) (l){$\mathbf K_m$};
\node at (O |- l) {$\mathbf K_1$};
\node at (t3 |- l) {$\mathbf K_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need complete graph K_m. But now I can try for it. Thanks.

Comment: I have a problem with it. I want to draw it for different $m$. How can i create $K_m$ in 3D. I think it is difficult to define coordinates of nodes. See edit in question also.

Comment: The solution is for K_4, and 4 vertices are on the same y=0 plane (X-Z plane). If you want it to be 3D, just assign different coordinates to y coordinates of the vertices, say, d3, d4 points. In your edit, no $...$ is needed as said in purcusse's comments.

Comment: Is that an octagon for the 3D convex hull?

Comment: According to the definition of convex hull, It seems true. But as I need, It is Complete graph on 8 vertices.

Answer (score 4):

TikZ supports a basic 3d coordinate system. You can change the view by explaining what z vector is in terms of x and y (see the manual). So you can start with this;

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (2,-1,0) coordinate (a)
          -- (2.5,0.3,0.5) coordinate (b)
          -- (2,0.5,0) coordinate (c)
          -- (1.5,0.2,0.2) coordinate (d)
           -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thick] (3.7,-0.5,0.5) coordinate (e)
          -- (4.5,0.3,0.5) coordinate (f)
          -- (3.5,0.5,0) coordinate (g)
           -- cycle;
\draw \foreach\x in{a,...,d}{(0,0,0)-- (\x)};
\draw \foreach\x in{a,...,d}{\foreach\y in{e,f,g}{(\x)-- (\y)}};
\draw (a)--(c) (b)--(d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]